# How to copy a Cutout from one Object to another

Tags: modeling

I have created a number of bearings.  All are now positioned where I want them. I cut out a center hole for the axle in one of the bearings.  Is there a way to copy that feature to the other bearings?

I know I should have duplicated the bearing after I had made all my changes.  I just want to learn if there is a way to copy shapes from object to object.

Comment: Do you know how to duplicate [Shift D], separate [P] and join [Ctrl J] objects/vertices?

Comment: I know Shift-D,  I know separate parts tab(edit) P.  Have not used join with Ctrl J, but use join on tool menu.

Comment: Thank you for the lesson.  I was able to copy and duplicate the internal vertices.  Then move the duplicate vertices forming the hole to next bearing and join it to the bearing.  My only problem was I still ended up using Knife Project to cut holes in the faces of the bearing.  If you post your suggestion as an answer I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Haven't got much time right now. But it would be great, if you could answer your question yourself (since you know what helped). Preferably with a screenshot demonstrating the solution (if possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the instructions provided by Leander, this is how a copied a hole from one object and added to another similar object.  Note - there are other easier ways to do this like Knife Project or simply making one object and duplicating it. But I wanted to learn.

1. Select object to copy from and tab into edit mode
   [image]
2. Select vertices outlining the feature (hole) to copy.  In this case also selecting the faces which will replace the faces on the object to be modified.
3. Shft-D to duplicate the vertices and move them to the side
   [image]
4. Separate the duplicate vertices from the original object by clicking P and selecting by loose parts
   [image]
5. I should have done this next. Select other object and tab into edit mode. Select faces to be replaced and delete them. Exit edit mode.
   [image]
6. Select duplicate vertices and Set Origin to Geometry
   [image]
7. Select object to be modified and center cursor on object Shft-S cursor to selection
8. Select duplicate vertices and Shft-S selection to cursor
9. Add new object to duplicate vertices Shft-LMB
10. Join vertices and new object Ctrl-J join
    [image]
    [image]